# OpenMP for C in eclipse IDE in Ubuntu/linux

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, gcc, openmp

I am using Eclipse IDE on ubuntu to code in C. I use its normal debugging and default compiler ( GCC )

am writing code with OpenMP features. Eclipse just skips the pragmas and compiles the code in serial. So I end up running the program from terminal with the -fopenmp parameters.

I was wondering if there is a way to make eclipse compile and debug the OpenMP parts as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to `Build > Settings > Miscellaneous > All options` and add `-fopenmp`.

Comment: sorry but could you be more specific ? where exactly do I find this ?